# Invisible gjs overlay prevents UI interaction

Tags: gnome, 21.10

A couple of days ago an issue started to appear after waking from sleep where I was unable to interact with any application on the first workspace visible after signing back in. The issue was tracked down to be gjs, which has put a transparent overlay atop the workspace, making everything underneath it inaccessible without first using an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image: Gnome's JavaScript Thing]

Although the gjs process does have an option to "Quit", the menu action does no such thing. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is also useless to eliminate this nuisance.

Searches for solutions online generally say that rebooting is the most appropriate fix, but I refuse to accept this as a viable answer as it's disruptive and can be worked around with an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This is happening only on my Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 installation. Other systems have never surfaced this issue.

Has anybody found a proper fix for this annoyance?

Comment: Does restarting gnome shell change anything (Alt+F2 r)? If not, it may be a misbehaving extension.

Comment: @yut23 restarting Gnome will resolve the issue until the next time the machine is woken from sleep, but it's still an annoyance as I will lock my machine every time I stand up from my desk, which is at least a dozen times throughout the day 

Answer (score 1):

I totally removed `gjs`
`sudo apt purge gjs --autoremove`

to my great surprise and after a reboot, no particular worries and especially no more gjs

Answer (score 0):

I see that too. Try `killall gjs`, that will it make go away till next time. Perhaps uninstalling the gjs package helps.